# CMake cannot find QXmlSimpleReader

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt5

I have a C++ header file which has the following lines:

```
#include <QXmlSimpleReader>
#include <QXmlDefaultHandler>
```

and my cmake has the following lines:

```
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Xml REQUIRED)
```

When running CMake I get the following error message:

```
QXmlSimpleReader: No such file or directory
 #include <QXmlSimpleReader>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please post the whole content of your cmake? What is your version of cmake?

Answer (score 2):

For some reason it do not adds to project include dirs.

Add this one to your cmake

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${Qt5Xml_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you forgot to link against Qt5xml. A working example from the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html) for cmake 2.8.11 and later, modified to link against Qt5Xml:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

project(testproject)

# Find includes in corresponding build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
# Instruct CMake to run moc automatically when needed.
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

# Find the QtWidgets library
find_package(Qt5Xml)

# Tell CMake to create the helloworld executable
add_executable(helloworld WIN32 main.cpp)

# Use the Widgets module from Qt 5.
target_link_libraries(helloworld Qt5::Xml)
```

Comment: He have compiling issue, not linking

Comment: target_link_libraries manages include paths in modern cmake: if it has not been called, include paths will be missing too -> compiling issue

Comment: Wow, never heard about this feature. Find package could update include dirs on the other hand. Any link to read? Could not found any mentions in cmake docs.

Comment: I can't find where I saw it in the doc, but the Qt cmake packages declare [imported targets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#imported-targets) populated with the lib paths AND the include paths. You see how the imported target is created in a Qt installation in `<qt_root_dir>/lib/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfig.cmake`: search for a call to `add_library`. Note that you can generate such a file by [installing exports](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/install.html#id7).

Comment: *.cmake files are processed when you call find_package. In qt those files populate include dirs and create properties which contain path to lib file. target_link_library just populate list of libs that you want to link to your app/lib. It just resolve names, and if you think you would understand that from point of build tool it is pointless to update include dirs. It is to late.

Comment: That's the old way :) The new way is based on imported targets

Comment: That's cmake way =)

Comment: The new cmake way is based on imported target :)

Comment: I got it: see [this link](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html#prop_tgt:INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES). And I used it in a project, so I can confirm you that way is really working ^^